# cwRsync ignores "nontsec" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, cwrsync

I use cwRsync to sync up some file from Windows to Ubuntu. This process used to work fine on Vista, but since I upgraded to Windows7, I keep getting permission issues.

Some background... I did use to get the same permission issues on Vista, but that was resolved by using the `CYGWIN=nontsec` environment variable.

**The premission problem**

```
rsync: failed to modify permissions on xxx: Permission denied (13)
```

Since windows and UNIX file permissions differ, sync'ing files with windows permissions doesn't make sense. What rsync does is set the permission on the UNIX side to 0 (`d---------`). To prevent this, cygwin has the `nontsec` variable which instructs it to ignore the windows file permissions.

The problem is, on Windows7, `nontsec` appears not to have any effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

re your solution, I had to make an adjustment to see it work for me - instead of your etc/fstab content, I used this content from the forum topic you reference:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0
```

I'm using cwRsync installer 4.0.3. I'm happy enough that it works for me but I can't offer a reason why, not being familiar enough with fstab syntax and options. Hopefully it adds something useful to someone else.

Comment: Yours might well be the right answer too. I'm not that familiar with the fstab options either, so I just put down whatever worked for me. I think the important option to use is the `noacl`. The rest may be different based on your specific choices.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that it wasn't Windows 7 that was causing the issue. Rather, it was the new version of cwrsync that was ignoring the `nontsec` environment var. For cwRsync versions **higher than 1.7**, you need to use the `noacl` option. (see forum topic: [No access to subfolders of RSYNC backup folder](http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=20038))

The solution involves creating an `fstab` file with the `noacl` option:

```
# In this example, my cwRsync dir is located at: "C:/Program Files (x86)/cwRsync"
# Filename: "C:/Program Files (x86)/cwRsync/etc/fstab"
C:/Program\040Files\040(x86)/cwRsync / ntfs override,binary,noacl 0 0
C:/Program\040Files\040(x86)/cwRsync/bin /usr/bin ntfs override,binary,noacl 0 0
```

And that's it! You can also remove the `CYGWIN=nontsec` env var since it's no longer used.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem copying from my Solaris based webhost down to my local PC.  The PC permissions were wacked when the files were copied down.  I setup the fstab file but no go.

In the end I realized  that I was making a full path call to rsync.exe which meant my current directory was no picking up the etc folder I just created.  To resolve this, I added these lines just above the call to the rsync command and it worked perfectly.

```
SET CWRSYNCHOME=%PROGRAMFILES%\CWRSYNC
c:
cd %CWRSYNCHOME%
```

Now my file permissions are correctly defaulting to the parent folder permissions without issues.

I just wanted to tag this onto this thread in case anyone else in the future is coming across the same issue I was.

Answer (score 2):

This is now also addressed in the cwrsync FAQ:
http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/11324

I can also report the fix in the FAQ (and Raise's answer) worked for me as well.

Comment: I wish this fixed it, but it's not helping for me. Perhaps my fstab is not in the correct location or something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but none of the solutions worked for me, until I realized my destination folder was outside the rsync folder. (I wanted to rsync files from Linux to Windows.)

Here is what worked for me:

1. Create a subdir `etc` inside the cwRsync folder (that is, where the `rsync.exe` resides).
2. Create a file named `fstab` (no suffix) inside that folder.
3. Insert one line into that `fstab` file, be sure to have UNIX line endings!

   ```
   none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0
   ```
4. Set environment:

   ```
   SET CWRSYNCHOME=<cwRsync installation path>
   SET HOME=<Directory to save user configuration files, like ssh known_hosts>
   ```
5. Before starting rsync.exe (this was the most important step in my case):

   ```
   cd <Destination folder>
   ```

The `SET HOME` part is important for SSH, it will create a `.ssh` subfolder there with a `known_hosts` file.