# Deploying Symfony Projekt using Rsync in Windows 7 - Permission Problem

Tags: symfony1, cygwin, rsync, cwrsync

I am desperetly trying to deploy my Symfony app with Rsync.

I instally cwRsync and it somewhat works, at least SSH does. My app is located in E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject.

Rsync actually does create one directory on my Server but other than that, I only get permission errors.

Now, this seems to be a common problem, however I am not able to implement any solutions, such as this one:
[cwRsync ignores "nontsec" on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124169/cwrsync-ignores-nontsec-on-windows-7)

I installed cwRsync to the following directory: c:\cwrsync

My Question: what does my fstab file need to look like, and where do I even have to put it? Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question you reference is essentially the solution - just create a file in `C:\cwRsync\etc` called `fstab` and add the line `none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd posted that question you referred to. Here's what I ended up doing to get symfony `project:deploy` to work from Windows 7 (it required hacking symfony a bit, so it may not be the most optimal solution). With this solution, you don't need fullblown cygwin installed, you just need cwRsync.

In your `fstab`, add this line (fstab should be located under  `[cwrsync install dir]\etc`):

```
C:/wamp/www /www ntfs binary,noacl 0 0
```

This essentially maps "C:\wamp\www" on your windows filesystem to "/www" for cygwin.

Modify `symfony/lib/task/sfProjectDeployTask.class.php`:

```
protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{
  ...
  $dryRun = $options['go'] ? '' : '--dry-run';

  // -- start hack --
  if(isset($properties['src']))
    $src = $properties['src'];
  else
    $src = './';

  $command = "rsync $dryRun $parameters -e $ssh $src $user$host:$dir";
  // -- end hack --

  $this->getFilesystem()->execute($command, $options['trace'] ? array($this, 'logOutput') : null, array($this, 'logErrors'));

  $this->clearBuffers();
}
```

This allows you to specify an additional `src` field in `properties.ini`:

```
src=/www/myProject
```

Doing this makes the whole filesystem mapping between windows and cygwin much more clearly defined. Cygwin (and cwRsync) understand unix paths much better than windows paths (i.e. `/www` vs. `C:/wamp/www`), so doing this makes everything just work.

Answer (score 0):

## Run a Script

I think Rsync always breaks your file permissions during sync between Windows and Linux.

You can quite easily create a script that goes through your file after a sync and resets the file permissions using chmod though.